# How to filter multiple fields in Firestore Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I need to search and filter from the Firestore collection. A sample collection with the name "products" is given below.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "product 1",
    "description": "product description 1",
    "categoryId": 35,
    "categoryName": "Category 123",
    .......
  },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "product 2",
    "description": "product description 2",
    "categoryId": 44,
    "categoryName": "Category 72",
    .......
  }
]
```

For example, if I entered a search text, I need a result from the Firestore collection where any of the fields contains a full or partial portion of the search text. Also, each product contains manufacturing and expiry dates. So I need to filter between a date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial text search is not a supported feature with Firestore, it uses a direct comparison for values.

You will have to implement a custom search feature yourself by 3rd party API like Algolia with cloud functions or create a breakdown of all the text in strings that support broken down letter combinations - but this can increase reads unwantedly and I do not recommend it.

Comment: I think it is better to switch to AWS and do whatever we want. Because of the lack of join I have to perform some additional tasks with cloud functions. Now for this simple filtering, I have to again depend on another service. In this case, it is a third party.

Comment: that is entirely up to you, text search is a multi-faceted concept and can be divided into multiple solutions. And using multiple solutions is not out of the ordinary in any project. Firebase is a Restful SAAS and as such does not have any CPU or server overhead to do complex algorithmic sorting. it's why it has a free tier.

Comment: Will there be any extra read happen if I install Algolia. Also, will there be any delay

Comment: Algolia is its own solution that returns document ID's for you to fetch, this introduces a delay but it is quite fast and is not noticeable to most users. the reads itself are done through algolia, not firebase